# Windows Server 2012 Datacentre R2 install gets stuck at getting devices ready

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have tried everything, including removing all peripherals from the server, and doing the reinstall again. Anyone know what I can do? Regards
EDIT: I have a HP Proliant Microserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/hp-proliant-n40l-81-installation-freeze-network/5626c5a5-3240-4ba0-b994-10d10cd7d529?page=4 flashing the latest BIOS should fix the problem: http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/pubsw-windows/p1657370250/v93269/SP64420.exe